# How to set the TextInputLayout error Color and size dynamically With Code

Tags: java, android

I want to take app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextLabelInput" In the Dynamic TextInputLayout Than How to Use it.

```
  <style name="TextLabelInput" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/solid_red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/solid_red</item>
    <item name="android:duration">200</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/solid_red</item>

    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/solid_red</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/solid_red</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/solid_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/solid_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/solid_red</item>


</style>

TextInputLayout input
input = new TextInputLayout(this);

input.setLayoutParams(lparams);
input.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: `setHintTextAppearance(int)` ?

Comment: The Only Hint Color change But i want to Change the Floating under label color and textsize

Comment: floating?  what floating?

Comment: Error Message which are under Edittext i take

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Soultion for this. I am doing this in my code

```
<!-- Firstly Make a Xml of TextInputLayout and Edittext Layout -->

 <!-- Text Input Layout-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextLabelInput"
 />


<!-- Edittext Layout -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
android:textColorHint="@color/txt_color"
android:textColorHighlight="@color/txt_color"
android:textSize="21sp" />


 <!-- In code add this with dynamic Text -->

TextInputLayout input

input = new TextInputLayout(this);
  input =(TextInputLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_inputlayout_item, null);

input.setLayoutParams(lparams);
input.setTypeface(tf);


et= new EditText(this);
et= (EditText)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_edittext_form, null);
et.setId(Integer.parseInt(item.getFieldid()));
et.setLayoutParams(lparams);
et.setHint(item.getLabel());
input.addView(et);
rl_MainLayout1.addView(input);
```